# BigEndian, LittleEndian Confusion In Xuggler

Tags: java, xuggler, endianness

Previously I posed a question about converting a `byte[]` to `short[]` and a new problem I encountered is converting/ not converting the data from `byte[]` to BigEndian.
Here is what is going on:

I am using `TargetDataLine` to read data into a `byte[10000]`.

The `AudioFormat` object has `BigEndian` set to **true**, arbitrarily.

This `byte[]` needs to be converted to `short[]` so that it can be encoded using Xuggler

I don't know whether the `AudioFormat` BigEndian should be set to true or false.
I have tried both the cases and I get an Exception in both the cases.
To convert `byte[]` to `short[]`, I do this:

```
fromMic.read(tempBufferByte, 0, tempBufferByte.length);
for(int i=0;i<tempBufferShort.length;i++){
tempBufferShort[i] = (short) tempBufferByte[i];
}
```

where:
`fromMic` is `TargetDataLine`
`tempBufferbyte` is `byte[10000]`
`tempBufferShort` is `short[10000]`
I get the Exception:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to write packet: com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@90098448[complete:true;dts:12;pts:12;size:72;key:true;flags:1;stream index:1;duration:1;position:-1;time base:9/125;]
```

---

### Miscellaneous information that may be needed:

How I set the stream for adding audio in Xuggler:

```
writer.addAudioStream(0,1,fmt.getChannels(),(int)fmt.getSampleRate());
```

How I perform the encoding

```
writer.encodeAudio(1,tempBufferShort,timeStamp,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

### Java Doc on AudioFormat

> ...In addition to the encoding, the audio format includes other
>   properties that further specify the exact arrangement of the data.
>   These include the number of channels, sample rate, sample size, byte
>   order, frame rate, and frame size...

**and**

> For 16-bit samples (or any other sample size larger than a byte), byte
>   order is important; the bytes in each sample are arranged in either
>   the "little-endian" or "big-endian" style.

### Questions:

Do I need to keep the `BigEndian` as **true** in `javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat` object?

What is causing the error? Is it the format?

---

I guess I get BigEndian data preformatted by the AudioFormat object.

Comment: Are you sure the cast is appropriate?  If you shorts are unsigned you will get allot of noise. BTW Failed to write packet is a message, not an exception. Can you give us the actual exception as it may have nothing to do with encoding.

Comment: That is the exception I get. I used `System.out.println(e)` to get what it contains. And I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to write packet: com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@90098448[complete:true;dts:12;pts:12;size:72;key:true;flags:1;stream index:1;duration:1;position:-1;time base:9/125;]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is indeed big endian, you can directly convert it to a (big endian) short array like this:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(originalByteArray);
short[] shortArray = buf.asShortBuffer().array();
```

The resulting `short` array will have all the original `byte` array directly, and correctly, mapped, given that your data is big endian. So, an original array, such as:

```
// bytes
[00], [ae], [00], [7f]
```

will be converted to:

```
// shorts
[00ae], [007f]
```

Comment: `short[] shortArray = buf.asShortBuffer().array;` flagged as unsupported operation

Comment: the problem is that Xuggler guys can not be contacted. Else, I would pose them this question.

Comment: @LittleChild one thing you _have_ to remember is that at the JVM level, all primitive numeric data types (this includes `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, but also `float` and `double`) are handled the big endian way, also called the MSB way, ie the Most Significant Byte first way. I don't know the API exactly, but I guess it arranges so that if you specify to read it the MSB way, it will match what Java "natively" expects for primitive types -- and I fail to see why it would ever offer the other way around as a choice... At this point, your best bet is to try and see what happens :/

Comment: Xuggler guys need to be more accessible. Now, only some veteran who has used Xuggler can help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert **two bytes** into **one short**, so this line is wrong:

```
tempBufferShort[i] = (short) tempBufferByte[i];
```

You need something along the lines of

```
tempBufferShort[i] = (short) 
   (tempBufferByte[i*2] & 0xFF)*256 + (tempBufferByte[i*2+1] & 0xFF);
```

This would be in line with a big-endian byte array.

Comment: `ByteBuffer` can also be used and I guess it does the conversion automatically using `order(ByteBuffer.BIG_ENDIAN)` right?

Comment: Yes, the approach with `ByteBuffer` involves the ready-made API for this purpose.

Comment: `bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(tempBufferByte);
   tempBufferShort = bb.asShortBuffer().array();` is flagged as unsupported operation.

Comment: Yes; that wouldn't be an appropriate usage of the API. `asShortBuffer` just creates a view of the original buffer; the view has no backing array (`hasArray` returns `false`, as documented).

Comment: I guess problem is with Xuggler. See the text about JavaDoc in question :) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

What others here have said about the byte-to-short conversion is correct, but it cannot cause the problem you see, it would just cause the output audio to be mostly noise.  You can call writeAudio with a buffer of all zeros (or anything, really) so, everything else being equal, the values in the buffer don't matter to whether the call succeeds (they do matter to what you hear in the output, of course :)

1. Does the exception happen at the beginning of the stream (first audio chunk)?  Can you write an audio-only stream successfully?
2. Set the audio codec when you call `addAudioStream`.   Try `ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MP3` or `ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_AAC`.
3. Check that `fmt.getChannels()` and `fmt.getSampleRate()` are correct.  Not all possible values are supported by any particular codec.  (2 ch, 44100 Hz should be supported by just about anything).
4. Are you writing your audio and video such that the timestamps are strictly non-decreasing?
5. Do you have enough audio samples for the duration your timestamps are indicating?  Does `tempBufferShort.length == ((timeStamp - lastTimeStamp) / 1e+9) * sampleRate * channels` ?  (This may be only approximately equal, but it should be very close, slight rounding errors probably ok).

Comment: Wait, I guess the issue is with 5th point, samples. I am having an issue there. With maintaining samples rate.